# jsp: page imports causing a syntax error

Tags: java, jsp, import, jspinclude

I'm writing a jsp application, what i did so far was to include the classes i need 
and to write the string text:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookException;" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookWebappHelper;" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookXmlRestClient;" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.code.facebookapi.IFacebookRestClient;" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.code.facebookapi.ProfileField;" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList;" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Collection;" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.EnumSet;" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap;" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;" %>
<%@ page import="org.w3c.dom.Document;" %>

test
```

I get the following error messages:

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 9 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 10 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 11 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 12 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 13 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

what am i missing?

thanks!

Comment: You're missing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear. remove that ';'

[ref](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm7.html)

Comment: ahah i know it seems like a really stupid question now. but the truth is that if i had 2 include lines with ; i did not get any error message. and on examples on the net people used ';', so anyhow thanks a lot! :)